# How to parse runtime variables to function call of chatgpt-3.5-turbo-1106?

Tags: python, chatgpt-api, gpt-3

While it is a well-known fact that the chatgpt-3.5-turbo-1106 can call functions by parsing arguments extracted from the user input, I am curious how we can parse our desired variable by code, not from user input extracted by GPT model.

Assuming we have defined the following function while creating an GPT assistant

```
{
    "type": "function",
    "function": {
                    "name": "store_to_db",
                    "description": "store captured data to DB",
                    "parameters": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                             "name": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "Name of the user."
                            },
                            "email": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "Email of the user."
                            },
                            "postcode": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "Postcode of the user."
                            },
                            "uuid": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "current uuid of user session"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": []
                    }
                }
}
```

the assistant model doesn't know what the uuid, because it can not be provided from the user's input, but only name, email, postcode.

In this case, i tried the following.

```
global uuid // uuid has been obtained somewhere in this code programmatically, not from GPT and user input.

if tool_call.function.name == "store_to_db":
          try:
            arguments = json.loads(tool_call.function.arguments)

            name = arguments.get("name", None)
            email = arguments.get("email", None)
            postcode = arguments.get("postcode", None)

            output = store_db(name=name, email=email, postcode=postcode, uuid=uuid)

            client.beta.threads.runs.submit_tool_outputs(thread_id=thread_id,
                                                        run_id=run.id,
                                                        tool_outputs=[{
                                                            "tool_call_id": tool_call.id,
                                                            "output": output
}])
```

Of course, this outputs an error that the argument is no defined.
Is there any workaround? Can not we go beyond the limitation of the current function call method of GPT model?